# Workflow Foundation - Can I make it fit?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have been researching workflow foundation for a week or so now, but have been aware of it and the concepts and use cases for it for many years, just never had the chance to dedicate any time to going deeper.

We now have some projects where we would benifit from a centralized business logic exposed as services as these projects require many different interfaces on different platforms I can see the "Business Logic Silos" occuring.

I have had a play around with some proof of concepts to discover what is possible and how it can be achieved and I must say, its a bit of a fundamental phase shift for a regular C# developer.

There are 3 things that I want to achieve:

1. Runtime instanciated state machines
2. Customizable by the user (perform different tasks in different orders and have unique functions called between states).
3. WCF exposed

So I have gone down the route of testing state machine workflows, xamlx wcf services, appfabric hosted services with persistance and monitoring, loading xamlx services from the databse at runtime, etc, but all of these examples seem not to play nicely together. For example, a hosted state machine service, when in appfabric, has issues with the sequence of service method calls such as:
"Operation 'MethodName' on service instance with identifier 'efa6654f-9132-40d8-b8d1-5e611dd645b1' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees".

Also, if you call instancial workflow services at runtime from an sql store, they cannot be tracked in appfabric.

I would like to Thank Ron Jacobs for all of his very helpful Hands On Labs and blog posts.

Are there any examples out there that anyone knows of that will tie together all of these concepts?

Am I trying to do something that is not possible or am I attempting this in the right way?

Thanks for all your help and any comments that you can make to assist.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error, it seems like you have modified the WF once deployed (is that #2 in your list?), hence the error you mention.

Versioning (or for this case, modifying a WF after it's been deployed) is something that will be improved in the coming version, but I don't think it will achieve what you need in #2 (if it is what I understood), as the same WF is used for every instance.